# Building a Web Interface for a Database

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, database

I have been working with MySQL Workbench the whole semester for my Database Management class. We have covered everything from relational algebra to SQL stored procedures, and the next assignment is a bit vague and broad

I need to make a web interface/application for the database that we have been manipulating. The assignment reads

"Your web application may be written in Java JSP/Servlets running on Tomcat or Glassfish Web Application Server, or Oracle JET or PHP or Node.js based"

However, no material was provided on any of those languages or engines. Could anyone point me towards the resources I need for making this interface? [Here are the requirements for the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQABs.png)

I have heard from my classmates that "using Python with Flask" is easier, so any resources or pointers or that would be very helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can recommend PHP laravel framework https://laravel.com/ for backend(Restful API) and Vue.js for frontend. Google on this keywords. In my opinion using this stack is the fastest way to develop such app

Comment: You can write all application (frontend+backend0 in Laravel (blade) - or in more modern fashion write backend Restful API in laravel as separate project, and Vue frontend which will consume that api as second project.

Comment: Be 'cool' and write a GraphQL service: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/demo%3a-graphql-with-node-oracledb

Answer (score 0):

If you have more experience with SQL than with traditional programming languages, the easiest way to build a small GUI on top of your database is probably to use a tool like [SQLPage](https://sql.ophir.dev), which will let you select from a list of predefined web components directly in SQL.

[image: SQLPage SQL GUI building diagram]